# Using pandas to generate new csv by comparing row2 of each, and excluding duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to take data from a csv file, let's call it **A** (contains user account info, with passwords, for active users in a program called IXL) and compare it to a csv file, call it **B**, that auto generates for all current active students, and create a new csv file that contains all info from A plus all info from B, except for rows where there are duplicates in column 3 (aka row2 of **hallpass_raw.csv**).

The python script I have so far, only generates the **B** csv file which I want to compare to the **A** csv file.

The **A** csv file contains current users and their current passwords. the **B** csv file would also contain those users but it creates a password which would cause  current users to not be able to login, so I want to exclude users where there are duplicates...

```
import csv
import subprocess

def ixl():
    with open(r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\hallpass_raw.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        with open(r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\ixl\ixl_raw.csv', mode='w', newline='') as output_file:
            write = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for row in csv_reader:
                subjects = 'Math, ELA'
                a = row[0]
                b = row[1]
                c = row[2]
                studentnumber = row[3]
                firstname = row[4]
                middlename = row[5]
                lastname = row[6]
                teacher = row[7]
                idnumber = row[8]
                phone = row[12]
                gradelevel = int(row[13])
                fatheremail = row[14]
                motheremail = row[15]
                studentemail = firstname + "." + lastname.replace(" ", "") + "@domain.org"
                username = idnumber + "@domain"
                password = idnumber + lastname
                father = row[9]

                # Only writes where grade is 3, 5, 7, or 9-12
                if (gradelevel == 5) or (gradelevel == 3) or (gradelevel == 7) or (gradelevel > 8):
                    write.writerow([lastname, firstname, idnumber, studentemail, gradelevel, teacher, subjects, username, password])


def main():
    """
    Controls the program execution
    :param in_file: the name of the input file.
    :return: None
    """

    ixl()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are the expected results:

**A** csv file **currentusers.csv** contains (row2 is the student **idnumber**):

```
john,smith,5456,john.smith@example.com,11,Jones,"Math,ELA",5456@domain,pass23
tara,smith,1234,tara.smith@example.com,10,North,"Math,ELA",1234@domain,pass67
matt,wells,2345,matt.wells@example.com,9,Jones,"Math,ELA",2345@domain,pass76
tony,dean,3456,tony.dean@example.com,12,Sims,"Math,ELA",3456@domain,pass19
eric,watts,4567,eric.watts@example.com,7,Sims,"Math,ELA",4567@domain,pass12
```

**B** csv file **ixl_raw.csv** contains: (this csv file is generated by the current script shown above, which contains all active students and will include users from **A** csv file, which causes the need to search for and remove duplicates based on row2)

```
john,smith,5456,john.smith@example.com,11,Jones,"Math,ELA",5456@domain,5456smith
tara,smith,1234,tara.smith@example.com,10,North,"Math,ELA",1234@domain,1234smith
matt,wells,2345,matt.wells@example.com,9,Jones,"Math,ELA",2345@domain,2345wells
tony,dean,3456,tony.dean@example.com,12,Sims,"Math,ELA",3456@domain,3456dean
eric,watts,4567,eric.watts@example.com,7,Sims,"Math,ELA",4567@domain,4567watts
new,student,5678,new.student@example.com,5,Parks,"Math,ELA:,5678@domain,5678student
```

If I upload **B** csv file to the **IXL** system, it would overwrite current users passwords, and current users would have no idea what their changed password is, and therefore could no longer sign in.

So instead, I want to compare **A** and **B** csv files, and generate a new csv file that would look like this:

```
john,smith,5456,john.smith@example.com,11,Jones,"Math,ELA",5456@domain,pass23
tara,smith,1234,tara.smith@example.com,10,North,"Math,ELA",1234@domain,pass67
matt,wells,2345,matt.wells@example.com,9,Jones,"Math,ELA",2345@domain,pass76
tony,dean,3456,tony.dean@example.com,12,Sims,"Math,ELA",3456@domain,pass1
eric,watts,4567,eric.watts@example.com,7,Sims,"Math,ELA",4567@domain,pass12
new,student,5678,new.student@example.com,5,Parks,"Math,ELA:,5678@domain,5678student
```

As you can see, this includes all current users from **A** and all users from **B** except those in **B** where there is a duplicate in the third column (aka row 2 of **ixl_raw.csv**, which is the student id number)

Comment: Wow! You work at IXL! I do that thing. lol

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your explanation of duplicate.  It sounds like you want to Right Join on B, which you can see an example of here: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

If that's the case:

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.read_csv("your/location/A.csv")
B = pd.read_csv("your/location/B.csv")

# Join with pandas merge; you're .csv's must have student_id column labeled to use this
C = pd.merge(A, B, on='student_id', how='right')

# create a new csv with joined data
C.to_csv("your/location/B.csv")
```

Comment: Im not sure that I explained well enough?  I have a csv, lets call it currentusers.csv, which contains current users with their logn names, emails, passwords, student id number, name, etc.  The python script I show above, takes all active students from a separate SIS system, and creates a csv file, lets call it newusers.csv, for all active students in that SIS system. Most of the info in newusers.csv already exists in currentusers.csv. I want to combine the two csv files, but I dont want any users info in the currentusers.csv file to be overwritten by info in newusers.csv,

Comment: ...(continued from above).... nor do I want their to be any duplicates. How i need to check for duplicates is the idnumber, because that is unique for each student. so in reality, a new csv file should be generated which contains all info from currentusers.csv AND, ONLY the info from newusers,csv where an idnumber doesnt already exist in currentusers.csv. I hope that helps to better explain?